# CSS property crop color background

Tags: html, css, colors, background

I would like to achieve in CSS a crop for the background color on only one side like this:

[image]
into this :

[image]

I found the property background-clip but It seems pointless in my case, do you have any ideas on how could I achieve this ? It's maybe a property of CSS that I don't know. Thanks for your help

Comment: Your code? (o_O)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving the "background" itself can simply be done by using `margin-left` (example below), however I won't be able to help you with the line going from the Introduction-text, to the left and outside the background myself. Obviously the colors in the example are wrong but you should get the idea.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: lightpink;
  padding-left: 50px;
  border-top: 50px solid gray;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1>Introduction</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: It was so simple that I didn't think of that, thanks a lot ! I manage to do what I wanted :)

Comment: @Pierre-AdrienDelisle No worries! Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 3):

Use multiple background with linear-gradient and adjust background size:

```css
.box {
  height:150px;
  background:
   /*The line*/
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) 10px 80%/150px 2px,
   /*The background*/
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) right top/calc(100% - 80px) 20px,
   linear-gradient(grey,grey) right/calc(100% - 80px) 100%;
   
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border:1px solid;
  padding-left:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `box-shadow inset`, It works if your blue line is not part of your background, because `box-shadow inset` hides a part of it

```css
div{
  background-color : #ccf;
  box-shadow: inset 25px 0 0 0 white; 
  height: 50px;
  color: black;
  border : 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
Here we have some text
</div>
```

Explanation :
`box-shadow: inset 25px 0 0 0 black;`

- `inset` : inside the box
- `25px` : position on X, so we move the shadow 25px to the right, which gives a 25px border on the left side
- `0 0 0` : position on Y, spead and blur
- `black` : the color, use `white` in your example